# Why will Pretty URLs not Work?

Tags: permalinks, htaccess

I have many security plugins setup. Could someone tell me what changes I need to make to my [`.htaccess`](http://pastebin.com/6VkejW2R) file (while keeping as much of my current rule set as possible) to make pretty URLs work?

```
# BEGIN iThemes Security - Do not modify or remove this line
# iThemes Security Config Details: 2
        # Enable HackRepair.com's blacklist feature - Security > Settings > Banned Users > Default Blacklist
        # Start HackRepair.com Blacklist
        RewriteEngine on
        # Start Abuse Agent Blocking
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Mozilla.*Indy" [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Mozilla.*NEWT" [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^$" [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Maxthon$" [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^SeaMonkey$" [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Acunetix" [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^binlar" [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^BlackWidow" [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Bolt 0" [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^BOT for JCE" [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Bot mailto\:craftbot@yahoo\.com" [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^casper" [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^checkprivacy" [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^ChinaClaw" [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^clshttp" [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^cmsworldmap" [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^comodo" [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Custo" [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Default Browser 0" [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^diavol" [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^DIIbot" [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^DISCo" [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^dotbot" [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Download Demon" [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^eCatch" [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^EirGrabber" [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^EmailCollector" [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^EmailSiphon" [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^EmailWolf" [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Express WebPictures" [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^extract" [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^ExtractorPro" [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^EyeNetIE" [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond

        # Protect System Files - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > System Files
        <files .htaccess>
                <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
                        Require all denied
                </IfModule>
                <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Deny from all
                </IfModule>
        </files>
        <files readme.html>
                <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
                        Require all denied
                </IfModule>
                <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Deny from all
                </IfModule>
        </files>
        <files readme.txt>
                <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
                        Require all denied
                </IfModule>
                <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Deny from all
                </IfModule>
        </files>
        <files install.php>
                <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
                        Require all denied
                </IfModule>
                <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Deny from all
                </IfModule>
        </files>
        <files wp-config.php>
                <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
                        Require all denied
                </IfModule>
                <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Deny from all
                </IfModule>
        </files>

        # Disable Directory Browsing - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > Directory Browsing
        Options -Indexes

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                RewriteEngine On

                # Protect System Files - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > System Files
                RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F]
                RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
                RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !^(.*)wp-includes/ms-files.php
                RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F]
                RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F]
                RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F]

                # Disable PHP in Uploads - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > Uploads
                RewriteRule ^wp\-content/uploads/.*\.(?:php[1-6]?|pht|phtml?)$ - [NC,F]

                # Filter Request Methods - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > Request Methods
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|DELETE|TRACK) [NC]
                RewriteRule ^.* - [F]

                # Filter Suspicious Query Strings in the URL - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > Suspicious Query Strings
                RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \.\.\/ [NC,OR]
                RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*\.(bash|git|hg|log|svn|swp|cvs) [NC,OR]
                RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} etc/passwd [NC,OR]
                RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} boot\.ini [NC,OR]
                RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ftp\:  [NC,OR]
                RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} http\:  [NC,OR]
                RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} https\:  [NC,OR]
                RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
                RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|%3D) [NC,OR]
                RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [NC,OR]
                RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(%24&x).* [NC,OR]
                RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(127\.0).* [NC,OR]
                RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(globals|encode|localhost|loopback).* [NC,OR]
                RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(request|concat|insert|union|declare).* [NC]
                RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^loggedout=true
                RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=jetpack-sso
                RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=rp
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in_.*$
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://maps\.googleapis\.com(.*)$
                RewriteRule ^.* - [F]

                # Filter Non-English Characters - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > Non-English Characters
                RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(%0|%A|%B|%C|%D|%E|%F).* [NC]
                RewriteRule ^.* - [F]

                # Reduce Comment Spam - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > Comment Spam
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /wp-comments-post\.php$
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$ [OR]
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(([^/]+\.)?sn0w\.io|jetpack\.wordpress\.com/jetpack-comment)(/|$) [NC]
                RewriteRule ^.* - [F]
        </IfModule>
# END iThemes Security - Do not modify or remove this line

#   BULLETPROOF .53.1 >>>>>>> SECURE .HTACCESS

# PHP/PHP.INI HANDLER/CACHE CODE
# Use BPS Custom Code to add php/php.ini Handler and Cache htaccess code and to save it permanently.
# Most Hosts do not have/use/require php/php.ini Handler htaccess code

# TURN OFF YOUR SERVER SIGNATURE
# Suppresses the footer line server version number and ServerName of the serving virtual host
ServerSignature Off

# DO NOT SHOW DIRECTORY LISTING
# Disallow mod_autoindex from displaying a directory listing
# If a 500 Internal Server Error occurs when activating Root BulletProof Mode
# copy the entire DO NOT SHOW DIRECTORY LISTING and DIRECTORY INDEX sections of code
# and paste it into BPS Custom Code and comment out Options -Indexes
# by adding a # sign in front of it.
# Example: #Options -Indexes
Options -Indexes

# DIRECTORY INDEX FORCE INDEX.PHP
# Use index.php as default directory index file. index.html will be ignored.
# If a 500 Internal Server Error occurs when activating Root BulletProof Mode
# copy the entire DO NOT SHOW DIRECTORY LISTING and DIRECTORY INDEX sections of code
# and paste it into BPS Custom Code and comment out DirectoryIndex
# by adding a # sign in front of it.
# Example: #DirectoryIndex index.php index.html /index.php
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html /index.php

# BRUTE FORCE LOGIN PAGE PROTECTION
# PLACEHOLDER ONLY
# Use BPS Custom Code to add Brute Force Login protection code and to save it permanently.
# See this link: http://forum.ait-pro.com/forums/topic/protect-login-page-from-brute-force-login-attacks/
# for more information.

# BPS ERROR LOGGING AND TRACKING
# Use BPS Custom Code to modify/edit/change this code and to save it permanently.
# BPS has premade 400 Bad Request, 403 Forbidden, 404 Not Found, 405 Method Not Allowed and
# 410 Gone template logging files that are used to track and log 400, 403, 404, 405 and 410 errors
# that occur on your website. When a hacker attempts to hack your website the hackers IP address,
# Host name, Request Method, Referering link, the file name or requested resource, the user agent
# of the hacker and the query string used in the hack attempt are logged.
# All BPS log files are htaccess protected so that only you can view them.
# The 400.php, 403.php, 404.php, 405.php and 410.php files are located in /wp-content/plugins/bulletproof-security/
# The 400, 403, 405 and 410 Error logging files are already set up and will automatically start logging errors
# after you install BPS and have activated BulletProof Mode for your Root folder.
# If you would like to log 404 errors you will need to copy the logging code in the BPS 404.php file
# to your Theme's 404.php template file. Simple instructions are included in the BPS 404.php file.
# You can open the BPS 404.php file using the WP Plugins Editor or manually editing the file.
# NOTE: By default WordPress automatically looks in your Theme's folder for a 404.php Theme template file.

ErrorDocument 400 /wp-content/plugins/bulletproof-security/400.php
ErrorDocument 401 default
ErrorDocument 403 /wp-content/plugins/bulletproof-security/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 405 /wp-content/plugins/bulletproof-security/405.php
ErrorDocument 410 /wp-content/plugins/bulletproof-security/410.php

# DENY ACCESS TO PROTECTED SERVER FILES AND FOLDERS
# Use BPS Custom Code to modify/edit/change this code and to save it permanently.
# Files and folders starting with a dot: .htaccess, .htpasswd, .errordocs, .logs
RedirectMatch 403 \.(htaccess|htpasswd|errordocs|logs)$

# WP-ADMIN/INCLUDES
# Use BPS Custom Code to remove this code permanently.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F]
RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F]

# WP REWRITE LOOP START
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# REQUEST METHODS FILTERED
# If you want to allow HEAD Requests use BPS Custom Code and copy
# this entire REQUEST METHODS FILTERED section of code to this BPS Custom Code
# text box: CUSTOM CODE REQUEST METHODS FILTERED.
# See the CUSTOM CODE REQUEST METHODS FILTERED help text for additional steps.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|DELETE|TRACK|DEBUG) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(HEAD) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=405,L]

# PLUGINS/THEMES AND VARIOUS EXPLOIT FILTER SKIP RULES
# To add plugin/theme skip/bypass rules use BPS Custom Code.
# The [S] flag is used to skip following rules. Skip rule [S=12] will skip 12 following RewriteRules.
# The skip rules MUST be in descending consecutive number order: 12, 11, 10, 9...
# If you delete a skip rule, change the other skip rule numbers accordingly.
# Examples: If RewriteRule [S=5] is deleted than change [S=6] to [S=5], [S=7] to [S=6], etc.
# If you add a new skip rule above skip rule 12 it will be skip rule 13: [S=13]

# Adminer MySQL management tool data populate
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-content/plugins/adminer/ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [S=12]
# Comment Spam Pack MU Plugin - CAPTCHA images not displaying
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-content/mu-plugins/custom-anti-spam/ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [S=11]
# Peters Custom Anti-Spam display CAPTCHA Image
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-content/plugins/peters-custom-anti-spam-image/ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [S=10]
# Status Updater plugin fb connect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-content/plugins/fb-status-updater/ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [S=9]
# Stream Video Player - Adding FLV Videos Blocked
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-content/plugins/stream-video-player/ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [S=8]
# XCloner 404 or 403 error when updating settings
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-content/plugins/xcloner-backup-and-restore/ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [S=7]
# BuddyPress Logout Redirect
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} action=logout&redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2F(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule . - [S=6]
# redirect_to=
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} redirect_to=(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule . - [S=5]
# Login Plugins Password Reset And Redirect 1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} action=resetpass&key=(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule . - [S=4]
# Login Plugins Password Reset And Redirect 2
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} action=rp&key=(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule . - [S=3]

# TIMTHUMB FORBID RFI and MISC FILE SKIP/BYPASS RULE
# Use BPS Custom Code to modify/edit/change this code and to save it permanently.
# Remote File Inclusion (RFI) security rules
# Note: Only whitelist your additional domains or files if needed - do not whitelist hacker domains or files
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(http|https|ftp)(%3A|:)(%2F|/)(%2F|/)(w){0,3}.?(blogger|picasa|blogspot|tsunami|petapolitik|photobucket|imgur|imageshack|wordpress\.com|img\.youtube|tinypic\.com|upload\.wikimedia|kkc|start-thegame).*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*(http|https|ftp)(%3A|:)(%2F|/)(%2F|/)(w){0,3}.?(blogger|picasa|blogspot|tsunami|petapolitik|photobucket|imgur|imageshack|wordpress\.com|img\.youtube|tinypic\.com|upload\.wikimedia|kkc|start-thegame).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
# Example: Whitelist additional misc files: (example\.php|another-file\.php|phpthumb\.php|thumb\.php|thumbs\.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (timthumb\.php|phpthumb\.php|thumb\.php|thumbs\.php) [NC]
# Example: Whitelist additional website domains: RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^.*(YourWebsite.com|AnotherWebsite.com).*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^.*sn0w.io.*
RewriteRule . - [S=1]

# BEGIN BPSQSE BPS QUERY STRING EXPLOITS
# The libwww-perl User Agent is forbidden - Many bad bots use libwww-perl modules, but some good bots use it too.
# Good sites such as W3C use it for their W3C-LinkChecker.
# Use BPS Custom Code to add or remove user agents temporarily or permanently from the
# User Agent filters directly below or to modify/edit/change any of the other security code rules below.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (havij|libwww-perl|wget|python|nikto|curl|scan|java|winhttp|clshttp|loader) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (;|<|>|'|"|\)|\(|%0A|%0D|%22|%27|%28|%3C|%3E|%00).*(libwww-perl|wget|python|nikto|curl|scan|java|winhttp|HTTrack|clshttp|archiver|loader|email|harvest|extract|grab|miner) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\?|\*|%2a)+(%20+|\\s+|%20+\\s+|\\s+%20+|\\s+%20+\\s+)HTTP(:/|/) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} etc/passwd [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} cgi-bin [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (%0A|%0D|\\r|\\n) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} owssvr\.dll [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \.opendirviewer\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} users\.skynet\.be.* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=http:// [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=(\.\.//?)+ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=/([a-z0-9_.]//?)+ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \=PHP[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12} [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\.\./|%2e%2e%2f|%2e%2e/|\.\.%2f|%2e\.%2f|%2e\./|\.%2e%2f|\.%2e/) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ftp\: [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} http\: [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} https\: [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \=\|w\| [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)/self/(.*)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)cPath=http://(.*)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*embed.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^e]*e)+mbed.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*object.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^o]*o)+bject.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*iframe.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^i]*i)+frame.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_(en|de)code[^(]*\([^)]*\) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(\(|\)|<|>|%3c|%3e).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(\x00|\x04|\x08|\x0d|\x1b|\x20|\x3c|\x3e|\x7f).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (NULL|OUTFILE|LOAD_FILE) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\.{1,}/)+(motd|etc|bin) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (localhost|loopback|127\.0\.0\.1) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|>|'|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} concat[^\(]*\( [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} union([^s]*s)+elect [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} union([^a]*a)+ll([^s]*s)+elect [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \-[sdcr].*(allow_url_include|allow_url_fopen|safe_mode|disable_functions|auto_prepend_file) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (;|<|>|'|"|\)|%0A|%0D|%22|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).*(/\*|union|select|insert|drop|delete|update|cast|create|char|convert|alter|declare|order|script|set|md5|benchmark|encode) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (sp_executesql) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]
# END BPSQSE BPS QUERY STRING EXPLOITS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# WP REWRITE LOOP END

# DENY BROWSER ACCESS TO THESE FILES
# Use BPS Custom Code to modify/edit/change this code and to save it permanently.
# wp-config.php, bb-config.php, php.ini, php5.ini, readme.html
# To be able to view these files from a Browser, replace 127.0.0.1 with your actual
# current IP address. Comment out: #Deny from all and Uncomment: Allow from 127.0.0.1
# Note: The BPS System Info page displays which modules are loaded on your server.

<FilesMatch "^(wp-config\.php|php\.ini|php5\.ini|readme\.html|bb-config\.php)">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
#Allow from 127.0.0.1
</FilesMatch>

# HOTLINKING/FORBID COMMENT SPAMMERS/BLOCK BOTS/BLOCK IP/REDIRECT CODE
# PLACEHOLDER ONLY
# Use BPS Custom Code to add custom code and save it permanently here.


# BEGIN WordPress

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Do pretty URLs work with only the default .htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

Your htaccess do not have the default wordpress related rules, go to the permalink page and save, if it it doesn't help turn off plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Settings" > Permalinks > [click] Save Changes

You don't need to change anything in the Permalinks page, it just resets everything to correctly link up.